# regular expression for excluding IPs out of range

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am using google analytics and have a filter for one of the websites to exclude traffic that is not within an IP range, but I am creating a new profile, to track all that traffic within that IP range. This will allow me two different profiles, one to view all traffic that is on campus, and another to view all traffic excluding campus-traffic.

The regular expression for the on-campus IP range is

```
^192\.245\.((2[5-8])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|29\.0)$
```

Would I just add ! to it, to set it as NOT in IP range, setting it to exclude all traffic that is outside this IP range, since I set it to NOT '!' in front of the IP range.

```
!^192\.245\.((2[5-8])\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1([0-9][0-9])|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|29\.0)$
```

The IP range is:

192.245.25.0 to 192.245.29.9

http://cl.ly/24376b03f80dfbf06d96

To sum it up, I want to have a profile that only tracks traffic within that IP range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not change the setting in the dialog to 'Include'?

The help documentation is very clear about what the meaning of the Include and Exclude filters.
See: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55559

Comment: I thought that, but also, it just might include all traffic, even the traffic within the IP range, so that may not work the way I want it to.

Comment: quick google returned http://www.waltervos.com/news/google-analytics-filter-include-all-traffic-from-an-ip-address/